# declare global variable in nsobject class (objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, global-variables

I declare a variable and some methods in the global nsobject class like

```
@interface classGlobal : NSObject {
    NSString *myGuid;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign)NSString *myGuid;
```

and i synthesize in the .m class. but when i try to access the myGuid variable in the same class (classGlobal.m) then it shows the error "instance variable 'myGuid' accessed in class method".
So please suggest how i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler complains, that you are using `myGuid` in a scope, where it is not accessible/defined. The declaration of `myGuid` in the `interface` part does **not** define a global variable, but an instance member variable. If you need a global variable (say, becaue you have to access it from a class method declared with `+` instead of `-`), declare as usual in your `.m` file:

```
MyClass.m:

    static NSString* myGuid = nil;

    + (void) someClassMethod {
        if( myGuid == nil ) ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that instance variables cannot be accessed from class methods. A class method is declared using a + instead of a -. If you need to use global variables I suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338195/global-variables-in-cocoa-objective-c) question which answers it pretty well. And here is [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113980/global-variables-in-objective-c).